# Recargado automatico de explorador

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy comenzando a aprender js con las librerías de p5, y me preguntaba si había alguna manera de refrescar automaticamente la ventana del navegador (uso firefox actualmente) cada vez que guardo los cambios efectuados al archivo de js.

Al ser todavía un simple programa, solo cuento con index.html y sketch.js.

¿Es posible refrescar la pagina automaticamente?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA_Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>sketch</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500,500);
}

function draw() {
    background(255/2);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 100);
}
```

Comment: Hola, serviría de mucho ver que has escrito (código). También que echaras un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @FernandoCarraro EDIT

Comment: Tu código html/javascript es para mostrar un círculo manipulado por el mouse.¿Para qué requieres refrescar? ¿Qué has investigado al respecto?

Comment: quiero saber como hacer para que cada vez que guardo un cambio en el archivo sketch.js o index.html, la ventana del navegador se refresque automaticamente. la pregunta no aplica solamente a estas lineas de codigo, si no que me gustaria aplicarla a cualquier proyecto en el futuro

Answer (score 0):

> me preguntaba si había alguna manera de refrescar automaticamente la
>   ventana del navegador (uso firefox actualmente) cada vez que guardo
>   los cambios efectuados al archivo de js

En todo caso para refrescar tu página puedes optar por usar window.location.reload(); en Javascript  o colocar `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">` directamente en tu html.

Links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/refresh-a-page-using-javascript-or-html

Comment: Gracias! la primera se asemeja mas a lo que buscaba. Me quedo asi: function mouseClicked() {
    window.location.reload();
}